# How to use external monitor with MacBook Air closed and on battery power?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, power

I often use my MacBook Air (running OS X 10.9.5) closed at a docking station, where it's hooked to external monitor, keyboard/trackpad, and power. All good. The only issue is that occasionally the external power will come loose or jostle*, which turns off the external monitor or causes it to flicker. I understand the system is designed to work this way -- no external monitor when closed unless the power is plugged in.

My question is: how to change this default behavior? i.e. keep the external monitor going while closed on battery power?

[*] Why you ask? My loving, atttention-seeking cats.

Comment: put a very heavy weight object on to the magsafe cable right next to the plug

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can. All you need is an app such as [NoSleep](https://code.google.com/p/macosx-nosleep-extension/).

[image: NoSleep]

Comment: THANK YOU! Apple's stupid MagSafe 2 + my cats can coexist. Harmony has been restored to my universe.

Comment: does not work for El Capitan, and I think for major versions, error installing pkg file

Answer (score 4):

In case it helps anyone who isn't comfortable downloading an app for this. I have the exact same need when I forget to bring my AC Adapter to the office, and I've worked around it by simply:

1. Mirroring the 2 displays (MacBook's & external)
2. Dimm the MacBook display all the way down to *off* (press `F1` until the display turns off)

I still can't close the lid, but my battery saving needs are met.

Comment: Came across this thread as I left my charger at home and want to preserve as much power throughout my work day using external monitor. Solid solution. Thanks.